# Receive different ajax requests in one PHP file

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I have three different html forms and submit my data with three ajax requests.  Do I have to send the data to three different PHP files, or is there a way to recive the request in one and the same PHP file?  Like calling a PHP function instead of calling the whole file.  In Java it is possible via a `@Path` ressource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use `IF` statements can't you? So try something like:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["item1"]))
{ 
    //do first post functions
}
else if(isset($_POST["item2"]))
{
    //do second post functions
}
else if(isset($_POST["item3"]))
{
    //do third post functions}
else
{
    echo "No post values found!";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. While using ajax you can specify which file you call. You can use one file in many calls.

```
 xmlhttp.open("GET", "gethint.php?q=" + str, true);
```

however you will need to build some logic (as mentioned in previous answer) which will decide and call specific function in that file.

[you can find something to start here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `switch`

```
$requestRecived = $_POST['YOUR_VARIABLE'];

switch($requestRecived){
    case 'page1':
        ....
        ....
    break;
    case 'page2':
        ....
        ....
    break;
    case 'page3':
        ....
        ....
    break;

}
```